# Add acf custom fields so sub item in menus

Tags: menus, sub-menu

Please, can anybody help me, I've been struggling so long with this

Basically, I want to add custom fields to sub menu items, I want to add an image and a link. I can see fields showing up in sub items in wp-admin, but on frontend, the image showed up on the main nav and there's only one image, I assume I need to do foreach? I don't want an image to show up on main nav, but in sub menu

This is my code so far:

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
```

function my_wp_nav_menu_items( $items, $args ) {

```
// get menu
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($args->menu);


// modify primary only
if( $args->theme_location == 'main-nav' ) {
    // vars
    $logo = get_field('logo', $menu);
    // prepend logo
    $html_logo = '<li class="menu-item-has-children"><img src="'.$logo['url'].'" alt="'.$logo['alt'].'" /></li>';
    // append html
    $items = $html_logo . $items;
}

// return
return $items;
```

}

This is the structure of my html:

```
    <li id="menu-item-22190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-22190 sub-test"><a href="text.com">Main Page with dropdown</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="menu-item-22188" class="remove-icon menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22188"><a href="text.com">Item One</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-22189" class="remove-icon menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-22189"><a href="test.com">Item Two</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I want these custom fields to show under sub-menu, inside li tag, please, is that possible? Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML output you're wanting?